# Android When to use BluetoothGatt.close()

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Android states this rather general statement about the use of the BluetoothGatt.close() method:
"Once your app has finished using a BLE device, it should call close() so the system can release resources appropriately"
However it is not clear what is meant by 'finished'. BTLE applications often save services and other info for faster responses on future connections. So does this mean one should call 'close()' on a disconnect (one is done with the device) or when one's application shuts down?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found by trial and error. In my current application I save the objects that implement the BluetoothGattCallback in a static List. There will be one object for each device that I connect to. I only call close() when I remove the object from my static List. I use the 'autoconnect = true' option which I understand to mean that on subsequent connections Android autoscans for advertisements from this device so one does not have to manually invoke the connection (one will need to be paired if the device requires it). It works reasonably well. I pair to a device, take a reading, use a UI to connect, and get the data. I take another reading and the device gives me the data without doing a connect. This is the expected behavior.

Now I implement with the close() upon disconnect. I can no longer re-connect manually or otherwise.